# How does stale behave when view is checkpointing?

Tags: couchdb

From what I can tell even if a view is indexing stale=ok will return results.
My question is, what does it do whilst a view is checkpointing?

If a view is being indexed and still checkpointing does stale=ok return the view as it was before any checkpointing started or does it return the view as it is at the last checkpoint during the current index build?

I guess what I am wondering is, can I use stale=ok to guarantee that a view is consistent (i.e. fully built), so there would be another process calling the view normally to get the index updated, but the UI will use stale=ok and always have a fully built index (even if sometimes out of date for a short while).

Hope that made sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CouchDB, transactions are limited to single document updates. Being [ACID compliant](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Technical%20Overview#ACID_Properties), query results are always consistent.

Martin Brown wrote some [tips to handle view updates](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/03/14/improving-couchdb-performance/).

Comment: This answer doesn't discuss stale views or checkpointing at all!